# Is there a way to permanently assign 0 to one of an array of registers in verilog?

Tags: verilog

Is there a synthesizable way to permanently assign the value to a particular memory location? I need a reg that is fixed at 0 and cannot be written to. All writes should be ignored and the register must remain 0.

Comment: Why is there such a need? Why not use a constant?

Comment: It needs to be indexable in a sequence of other registers. So, for example: reg [7:0] myReg [20:0]; if myReg[10] must be fixed at 0.

Comment: No, you cannot do that (I mean the read-only thing). It is your code who needs to make sure there are no writes performed to the specific index. For example you might want to write a procedure to exclusively access this array, and before the access to check the index.

Comment: If its always 0, why do you care if it's a reg or wire? Just make it a wire and assign it equal to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work for both synthesis and simulation, and should work for both ASIC and FPGA designs as it doesnt need an initial block.

```
wire imNothing = 0;
always @ * begin
    theReg <= imNothing;
end
```

This is basically equivalent to connecting `theReg` to the wire `imNothing` which is permanetly attached to 0.

---

Having said that, this doesn't stop you overwriting the value.

In the case of your comment, using an array for which some indexes you wish to always be zero, then the above would only work if you avoid writing to the register.

You basically have to manually add the checks as part of your code. For example if you are writing to a memory, you could do:

```
memory[addr] <= (addr == ingoreAddr) ? 0 : writeData;
```

Comment: Actually, that will never execute.

Comment: @dave_59 For simulation, you're right. That's quite amusing.

Comment: "always begin reg=0 end" works in simulation for some reason. Not sure why. I would have thought a forever statement would be needed. But I'm not sure this is synthesizable.

Comment: @Gacekky1 `always begin` is effectively, do this constantly. The reason for the `#1` is basically some simulators (ModelSim, I'm looking at you) will lock up without it.

Comment: @dave_59 realised where I'd gone wrong. Need to use a wire assigned to zero as an input to get it to behave itself.

Comment: @Gacekky1 I do think this is synthesizable but as Tom said it will synthesize to a wire connected to ground. The tools won't use transistors when a wire will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

`always @(posedge CLK) MyReg <= 0;`

And your synthesis tool will probably optimize it away to a constant 0. Why not use a parameter?

### UPDATE

Based one your question comments, you probably want to make particular memory locations appear that they are 0. Instead of referring to `mem[addr]` you would use `(addr==10 ? 0 : mem[addr])`